# How to build BOTH non-block components and blocks present in the /src directory using @wordpress/scripts

Tags: javascript, block-editor, react

I regularly use `@wordpress/scripts` for building both blocks and non-block components. Recently, I started working in a new plugin that registers both some blocks and non-block components that add additional panels using the `registerPlugin()` function. This is the structure of my `/src` directory:

```
/src
    /blocks
        /my-first-block
            block.json
            ...
        /my-second-block
            block.json
            ...
        /my-third-block 
            block.json
            ...
    /components
        /my-first-panel
            index.js
        /my-second-panel
            index.js
    index.js
    style.css
```

This is the content of the root `index.js` file:

```
import { registerPlugin } from '@wordpress/plugins';

import FirstPanelOptionsPanelComponent from './components/my-first-panel';
import SecondPanelOptionsPanelComponent from './components/my-second-panel';
import './style.scss';

registerPlugin('first-panel-options-panel', {
    render: FirstPanelOptionsPanelComponent,
});

registerPlugin('second-panel-options-panel', {
    render: SecondPanelOptionsPanelComponent,
});
```

When you run the `wp-scripts build` script from the `@wordpress/scripts` package, it only builds the blocks located in the `/src` directory. However, if you specifically run `wp-scripts build src/index.js`, it builds the components but exclude the blocks.

Is there a way to build BOTH the blocks and the non-block components at once?